# TableRow start with top margin in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I Have a TableLayout That inside of him I added TableRow dynamically by code.

My problem is that the row is added with a top margin.

This is part of the XML file:

```
     <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TLArchiveHeader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stretchColumns="*" >
                    </TableLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                 </ScrollView>
```

This is the code for creating a row:

```
private void CreateRow(String Fname,String roi, String scr, String velocity, String vscr, String msc )
    {
        TextView TVStat, TVMSC, TVDate;

        TableRow row;
        TableLayout TableTnside;


        TVStat = new TextView(this);
        TVMSC = new TextView(this);
        TVDate = new TextView(this);
        TVImage = new ImageView(this);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        row = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_layout , null);//new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        TableTnside = new TableLayout(this);
        //TableTnside.setLayoutParams(params);

        TVStat.setText("Itay");
        TVStat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        TVMSC.setText(msc);
        TVMSC.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        TVDate.setText(Fname);

        //new loadThumbnail().execute();
        thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FullPath,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

        new loadThumbnail().execute();
        //TVImage.setImageBitmap(thumb);

        TableTnside.addView(TVStat);
        TableTnside.addView(TVMSC);

        row.addView(TVImage);
        row.addView(TableTnside);
        row.addView(TVDate);

        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_unselected);

        row.setClickable(true);
        row.setOnClickListener(tablerowOnClickListener);
        MainTable.addView(row);
        TableRowCounter++;

    }
```

This is the result: [image]

As you can see the first row is hiding because of the margin.I didn't do any margin in my code and I don't know from where the margin came.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think it's happening because of overlapping. Test Results might be overlapping the table. You need to place  your scrollview below the heading.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are right.I just put the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.